# Why cases are not counted here?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Q)The number of 4 digit numbers that can be made with the digits 1,2,3,4 and 5 in which at least two are identical is?

Here,answer can be easily calculated by:
Ans=Number where repetition allowed-number where repetition is not allowed
$$Ans=5^4-5!=505$$

However, I also tried to count it separately and failed.My try:
Let _ _ _ _ be the number. Here, for exactly 2 identical numbers,3 numbers are selected from the 5 numbers. Out of these 3, one must be selected so that it is the repeated digit and all of this can be arranged in $4!/2!$ ways making it ${}^5C_3 \cdot {}^3C_1*4!/2!$.Same thinking is applied for 3 identical and 4 identical numbers, making the answer to be $${}^5C_3 \cdot {}^3C_1\cdot 4!/2!+{}^5C_2 \cdot {}^2C_1\cdot 4!/3!+{}^5C_1 \cdot {}^1C_1\cdot 4!/4!$$
$$=360+80+5=425$$But the individual counting is lacking 80 methods. Where have I gone wrong in counting the cases individually?

Comment: You're missing the cases of two of one number and two of another, like 4411.

Comment: That gives you 60 numbers you missed. The other 20 are because 360+80+5=445, not 425.